# JavaScriptSerializer serializes times inconsistently

Tags: c#, json, datetime

Two DateTimes go into a [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.100).aspx), both have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`

**One comes out an hour behind.** How can I make both dates serialize consitently?

*Input to JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize():*

```
 [DataMember]
 public DateTime? CoverStartDate { get; set; }

 [DataMember]
 public DriverInfo[] Drivers { get; set; }

 public class DriverInfo : IDriverInfo
 {
     [DataMember]
     public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
 }
```

[image]

*Output from JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize():*

```
{"SiteId":24,"RegionId":2,"SchemeId":null,"SchemeTypeId":null,"IsAnnual":null,"Drivers":[{"DisplayIndex":0,"Title":null,"FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"Age":51,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(-155001600000)\/","IsLeadDriver":true}],"CoverStartDate":"\/Date(1471042800000)\/","TripDuration":15}
```

[image]

How can I make both DateTimes serialize consistently?

Comment: if I remember right, microsoft dropped their own javascriptserializer somewhen around 2014, is it reasonable for you to use json.net ?

Comment: Yes it is reasonable, but I was hoping for a workaround instead :-(

Comment: [This covers it quite thoughly](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx). **Tl;Dr** use Json.Net and ISO-8601 format

Comment: Note that the feb date is outside of DST, while the aug date is within.  Likely the same logic is being applied to both (converting to local date/time), just that one of them happens to be the same as UTC, the other not.  Or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks James, that make sense :-)